# Can data be migrated from Stack Overflow for Teams Free plan to Business?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams

Is it possible to migrate from Free plan to the Business one without losing the data? This could be a typical scenario of evaluating the tool and then proceeding with the onboarding.

Comment: Curious. What makes you think the data could be lost? It wouldn't make much sense for a product of this kind.

Comment: I can imagine that meeting. "Oh yeah, and let's erase every question on the Q&A when the plan is upgraded, okay?"

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://stackoverflow.help/en/articles/4538400-view-plan-details-or-upgrade) it's a simple 3 steps to update your plan and it makes no mention that your existing environment would be wiped; that would be **terrible** idea if it did if I'm honest.

Comment: Well, the plans look to me like all are hosted on Stack Overflow, so I don't think anything happens to them when you up- or downgrade.

Comment: Enterprise does offer on premises hosting, @Tom . Though I am sure that Stack Overflow would be more than willing to assist in the migration for a customer if they wished to migrate to On-Premises when they were on a lower plan previously.

Comment: @Larnu, thank you for the documentation link